# Is this thread safe about RequestLifetimeHttpModule: ILifetimeScopeProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

First I will show you the source code of RequestLifetimeHttpModule which is designed in Autofac.Integrated.MVC. It's help us to keep the instances initiate only once per http request.

```
internal class RequestLifetimeHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    // Gets the lifetime scope provider that should be notified when a HTTP request
    // ends.
    internal static ILifetimeScopeProvider LifetimeScopeProvider { get; private set; }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public static void SetLifetimeScopeProvider(
        ILifetimeScopeProvider lifetimeScopeProvider)
    {
        if (lifetimeScopeProvider == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lifetimeScopeProvider");

        LifetimeScopeProvider = lifetimeScopeProvider;
    }

    static void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LifetimeScopeProvider != null)
            LifetimeScopeProvider.EndLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

}

The `ILifetimeScopeProvider` is designed as static field. So Is't thread safe?
When one my request is running and an another request is coming in at the safe time. I think
the second request will try to replace the static `ILifetimeScopeProvider` (Because it's by Class not by instance).

Comment: Who calls `SetLifetimeScopeProvider`? And how often is it called? And where is a life time scope started? Please show that code.

Comment: Hi Steven Thanks for you help. I think I may find the answer. Actually, the main purpose of the RequestLifetimeHttpModule is registe the EndRequest to the HttpApplication then it will keep a reference to the LifetimeScopeProvider.

So the LifetimeScopeProvider will be disposed as soon as the request end or by GC.

Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only place that the method is called is in the [constructor of RequestLifetimeScopeProvider](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/98d37597404e02aa783ca334ba8db4960cae7137/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/RequestLifetimeScopeProvider.cs#L52), which in turn is only called by the [AutofacDependencyResolver](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/82cc138596e74095f50720319feb2a2ce734310d/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/AutofacDependencyResolver.cs#L130).

As you can see on line 130, this is called in a singleton pattern, so there is no way it can be instatiated more than once per application start.